# Chocolately `Get-ExecutionPolicy` - Uncaught ReferenceError: Get is not defined

Tags: shell, command-line, chocolatey

I am following the [Chocolately Install](https://chocolatey.org/install) steps (Windows 7), but have run into a couple of problems.

Firstly, I've opened **Command Prompt** (opening it with **Run as administrator**), but when trying to execute `Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))`, I get this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

..with the `https:` part of my command highlighted.

Further, when I try to execute `Get-ExecutionPolicy`, it results in:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Get is not defined

Any ideas what could be wrong?

*** UPDATE ***

When I try the same command in **PowerShell**, I get this error:

> PS C:\Users\mylogin> Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force;
>   [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtoc ol =
>   [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex
>   ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString
>   ('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1')) Exception setting
>   "SecurityProtocol": "Cannot convert value "3312" to type
>   "System.Net.SecurityProtocolType" due to inv alid enumeration values.
>   Specify one of the following enumeration values and try again. The
>   possible enumeration values  are "Ssl3, Tls"." At line:1 char:85
>   + Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]:: <<<< SecurityProtocol = [System.
>   Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object
>   System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://ch
>   ocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException
>
> Exception calling "DownloadString" with "1" argument(s): "The
>   underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occ urred on a
>   send." At line:1 char:219
>   + Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.Se
>   rvicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object
>   System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString <<<< ('https://ch
>   ocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Comment: You are executing those commands in PowerShell? Is it PowerShell v2 ($PSVersionTable will tell you)?

Comment: I was executing them with Command Prompt. I've tried again with PowerShell and have updated my answer with the different error it gives. (Yes, my PSVersion is 2.0 .)

Comment: Why did they choose to make the installation so *incredibly* complicated? I have been using Microsoft Windows since the 90s, and I have never seen an installation procedure as complicated as this one. Why not simply let the user download a simple EXE file, or a ZIP file with EXE and helpers, or a simple "Next, Next, Next, Finish" setup EXE?

Comment: So... Did you fix this issue bro? What was the solution?

Answer (score 8):

1. Download chocolatey latest version from [Chocolatey.org](https://chocolatey.org/api/v2/package/chocolatey/)
2. Rename file extension to .zip
3. Extract the file
4. Open PowerShell
5. Open elevated PowerShell calling:

   ```
   Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs
   ```
6. Go to the tools folder in the location where you extracted Chocolatey
7. Call: `& .\chocolateyInstall.ps1` to allow Chocolatey to install
8. Add a path to the choco location to **system** environment PATH:

   ```
   C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin
   ```
9. Restart your consoles, and VS Code (if you use one)

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked on 32bit Windows 7 like a charm!

Comment: To extract `nupkg` just rename `chocolatey.0.10.15.nupkg ` to `chocolatey.0.10.15.zip` and use windows default extractor

Answer (score 7):

Chocolatey.org [requires TLS 1.2](https://chocolatey.org/blog/remove-support-for-old-tls-versions) to be able to connect. This error indicates that you don't have support for that installed:

```
System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString ('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1')) Exception setting "SecurityProtocol": "Cannot convert value "3312" to type "System.Net.SecurityProtocolType" due to inv alid enumeration values. Specify one of the following enumeration values and try again. The possible enumeration values are "Ssl3, Tls"
```

The section from the blog post I linked to earlier should help:

> If you find yourself provisioning machines such as Windows 7, Windows Server 2008, or older, you will find that those machines will not be able to communicate with the Chocolatey Community Repository after we implement this change. For those instances, you will need to use [alternative installation methods](https://chocolatey.org/docs/installation) for Chocolatey. We strongly recommend using the [offline Chocolatey installation](https://chocolatey.org/docs/installation#completely-offline-install) as it provides the most flexibility and reliability.

On the [Chocolatey install page](https://chocolatey.org/install) the requirements are listed:

- Windows 7+ / Windows Server 2003+
- PowerShell v2+ (minimum is v3 for install from this website due to [TLS 1.2 requirement](https://chocolatey.org/blog/remove-support-for-old-tls-versions))
- .NET Framework 4+ (the installation will attempt to install .NET 4.0 if you do not have it installed)(minimum is 4.5 for install from this website due to [TLS 1.2 requirement](https://chocolatey.org/blog/remove-support-for-old-tls-versions))

My suggestion would be to fully patch your Windows 7 system, install .NET 4.5 and then try it. Remember Windows 7 has been out of support since January this year.

Comment: Thank you. I've followed the two steps at https://chocolatey.org/docs/installation#completely-offline-install , so I now have `chocolatey.0.10.15.nupkg` downloaded. How I do I install it from here? (I've found https://chocolatey.org/docs/how-to-setup-offline-installation , but it's confusing.)

Comment: You will need to follow the code in the script file (https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1 - requires TLS1.2 to view) to install it. From memory it extracts the package and runs the chocolateyInstall.ps1 file - but check this as it's been a while since I looked at it.

Comment: Im using the alternative install for windows 7 and getting the same error Exception setting "SecurityProtocol": "Cannot convert value "3072" to type "Sys
tem.Net.SecurityProtocolType" due to invalid enumeration values. Specify one of
 the following enumeration values and try again. The possible enumeration value
s are "Ssl3, Tls"."

Comment: Windows 7 doesn't contain the ciphers for TLS 1.2 so trying to set it isn't going to work. You need to be doing a completely [offline install of Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/docs/installation#completely-offline-install).

Note that even after you install it you won't be able to use chocolatey.org to download packages as it requires TLS 1.2 so you'll need to be using an internal package repository.